# How to style circular-like div?

Tags: css

How can I style this circular div? It is not pure circle as you can see, it is slightly different, uneven but also nicely rounded.

[image]

I am trying with `border-radius` but it doesn't look as pretty, it seems like it has lumps

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 42%;
  transform: rotate(46deg);
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Comment: @BorisLeMéec it's not a circle

Comment: @MadisonCourto it's not a circle

Comment: It's known as a "squircle". See - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=squircle

Answer (score 1):

Make the border radius half the size of the width/height. You will have to be pretty clever about getting text and images to fit in the circle.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" >
</head>
<h1> Header </h1>
<p> Hi
<div class="circle" id="circle"> ! </div>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.circle {
  border-radius: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: green;
  margin: auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Result:

[image: Circle]

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like the problem here is that the size of your circle is larger than the one you are imitating.  Some modifications to the size, radius and rotation gives:

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 44%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  height: 66px;
  width: 66px;
  background: green;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Utilising Photoshop, pasting one circile over the other gives an almost perfect reproduction.

Comment: I don't think size matters, it can be 50px or 1000px but lumps don't look pretty :)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.circle {
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: rotate(46deg);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

now try to execute this one,it will work for sure.